# Insert result of inline evaluation

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, inline

In previous versions of Mathematica I could inline evaluate the call to Solve in the code below with the result replacing the call. Very useful to speed code up.

```
x = Function[t, (-900 + 30 t)];
y = Function[t, 10000];
sos = 1531;

Function[{p, T},
 Block[{t},
  t = t /. 
    Solve[T == 
       t + EuclideanDistance[{x[t], y[t]}, {p[[1]], p[[2]]}]/
         sos, {t}][[1]];
  t]]
```

In Mathematica 12 when I try the same trick the inserted value is in output format and is not valid as part of the input. How can I revert back to the previous behaviour?

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete and can not be evaluated. Therefore, no one can reproduce problem and, perhaps, solve it.

Comment: @m_goldberg I've added the other bits of code so it is replicable now. Inline expanding  "Solve[T ==  t + EuclideanDistance[{x[t], y[t]}, {p[[1]], p[[2]]}]/sos, {t}]" does not replace self with code acceptable for input.

Answer (score 1):

I using V11.3 and I can't reproduce your problem on that version. When I do an inline evaluation the block, I get a perfectly usable function — exactly what you want but are not getting.

[image: code]

I do have a suggestion, however. Try selection the code that is being displayed in output form and press <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (this is the MacOS shortcut, the will be similar shortcut on other systems). That should convert the selected code input form.